# Python - Dictionary from pyodbc return results in Type Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, pyodbc

I need to create a dictionary out of my pyodbc return because i want my wxPython Lists to be sortable by clicking on the header.

This is my code creating the Dictionary:

```
self.itemDataMap = {data : data for data in pyodbc_return}
```

The error looks like this:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'pyodbc.Row'
```

The Code where is gather my data from the Database looks like this:

```
def ExecQuery(self, sql, addition=""):        
    cur = self._Getconnect()
    
    if addition != "":
        cur.execute(sql, addition)
    else:
        cur.execute(sql)
    
    relist = cur.fetchall()
    
    cur.close()
    self.conn.close()
    
    return relist
```

What do i need to change to create a Dictionary out of my result?

Comment: `fetchall()` returns a list of `pyodbc.Row` objects. They look a lot like tuples, but they're not. So what do you really want when you say that you want to "create a dictionary out of my pyodbc return"? Do you want a `list` of `dict`? Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

`data` is a list, you could use:

```
self.itemDataMap = {tuple(data) : data for data in pyodbc_return}
```

I don't know why you want to do this.